# How can I do a bugfix on master and integrate it into my less stable branch(es)?

Tags: git, branching-strategy

I'm using Git for one of my projects at the moment, and I love it.

However, because I'm the only one working on my project, the only commands I've been using are

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m 'message here'
git push origin master
```

I have pushed the project to remote a long time ago ago (I Capistrano for deployment), and all is working great.

Now I want to change the design of the site, but keep the logic intact. I'm guessing I need to create a new branch (let's call it `newdesign`) for that.

What I'm wondering, though, is this: if I'm working on the `newdesign` branch, and I see a bug in the `master` branch, how can I fix the bug on `master` and then integrate that bugfix in the `newdesign` branch, so that the latter be kept up to date with the actual logic?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a classic case in which you can take advantage of Git branches. Here is the workflow you should use.

Let's say you've created a `develop` branch stemming from `master` and you've made a few commits on that branch:

[image]

Suddenly, you realise that there is a bug on `master`, a bug that you need to fix quickly. Instead of working directly off of `master`, you should create a short-lived *bug-fix* branch, to isolate the bug-fixing task from your `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b bugfix
```

[image]

After making one commit (or more) on the `bugfix` branch to fix the problem,

[image]

you should make sure that everything works as it should (run tests, etc.). When you're happy with the state of your code on `bugfix`, merge it into `master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix
```

[image]

At that stage, you can push your (now fixed) `master` branch to remote, and delete the `bugfix` branch:

```
git push origin master
git branch -d bugfix
```

Now, to integrate the latest changes on `master` into `develop`, you basically have two options.

1. Merge `master` into `develop`, by running:

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git merge master
   ```

[image]

2. Alternatively, rebase `develop` on top of `master`, by running:

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git rebase master
   ```

[image]

In either case, your `develop` branch will now contain the fix, and you can resume work on `develop`.

Comment: Owww ... Thank you so much for that ... That has answered my question quite well.

Comment: The bugfix branch doesn't seem necessary. You can just commit directly to master then `git rebase master develop`. Also, `rebase` only works if develop is not public.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I prefer using a bugfix branch: if my initial attempt at fixing the bug is going nowhere, I can just delete the bugfix branch and restart from scratch at `master`, rather than having to clean up my botched attempt on `master`.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and complete answer!

Comment: @Fiver You're welcome. I appreciate it :)

Comment: @jub0bs I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Answer (score 1):

let's suppose you have you master and dev branches.

You work on dev for your new features and you do your fix on master.

Then you checkout dev and merge master into dev.
This way master is fixed and dev can profit from the fix you made AND keeps it's own history.

Alternatively, you can rebase dev on top of branch. This gives you a "cleaner" history in the sense that you don't have merge points.

See the git guide about merging: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: Hey @vratojr ... But if i merged master into dev, wouldnt i lose the work on the new design i was doing in dev?

Comment: No you won't loose your changes in the dev branch ... what merge does is just copy the contents of one branch to the another branch where the target or another branch is running behind in commits

Comment: Ohhh i think i understand @justrohu ... So it will just copy over the changes from where the dev branched off from the master? Anything before that doesnt matter

Comment: @BigJobbies Yes it kinda copies that but if there are any other changes to Master branch those changes are saved too.