# Understanding git branching

Tags: git, branch

I have a newbie question about Git.

The scenario:

1) I create an "experiment" branch in a project

2) Then I decide to do a change (ex: add files to .gitignore) that must affect the "experiment"
 branch as well as the master branch or any future branch I would branch from the master branch.

What is recommended on that situation?

Checkout the latest commit on the master branch before branching and commit with `--amend`?

Create a branch to do just that and then merge with master and the experiment branch? When I tried to do this, I applied all that was on my "experiment" branch to the master branch and lost a whole lot of files. I'm very confused now... any help will be greatly appreciated

**update**

What happened (and I could not explain in my last paragraph above):

I actually had merged the 'hotfix' branch (which had the .gitignore commited) into the 'experiment' branch and then merged it from master (on the 'experiment' branch I had deleted a bunch of files).

So I used:

```
git checkout master
git reset —hard [hash for the previously last commit on master]
git branch -d hotfix
git checkout -b hotfix (now from master)
git add .gitignore
git commit -m “add .gitignore”
git checkout master
git merge hotfix
git checkout experiment
git merge hotfix
git branch -d hotfix
```

Then I kind of 'undid' that and did it again using the rebase method, from one of the answers below. It appealed more to me because of the 'history rewriting' thing, which makes more sense to me by looking to the branch graph. And i'm working alone (so far) on this project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a bugfix on master and integrate it into my less stable branch(es)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933056/how-can-i-do-a-bugfix-on-master-and-integrate-it-into-my-less-stable-branches)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understand the content of your last paragraph right. Have you surley merged in the right directions? Following procedure should work

```
git branch MaintainGitIgnore
git checkout MaintainGitIgnore

//manipulate .gitignore file
git commit -a .gitignore -m "Ignoring new files now"

git checkout master
git merge MaitainGitIgnore

git checkout experiment
git merge MaintainGitIgnore
```

You can now keep the branch MaintainGitIgnore, and maybe use a script to automate updating you ignore definition.

Comment: On the last line, will I get the same result if I use "git merge master" instead?

Comment: If and only if no other branches were merged to the master. Think about working on issue0 and spontaneously opening hotfix0, e.g. a bugfix. After fixing you merge hotfix0 to master, then checkout branch issue0 and continue regular work. That's like an example in the Git SCM reference http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html) after commiting the new `.gitignore` to the master branch.

`git checkout master
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Updates ignore list'
git checkout experiment
git rebase master`

This will update the `experiment` branch.

But, please, only do this if you are the only person working on this branch. If someone else is working as well, it will give conflict issues. In that case, I would merge the `master` branch in the `experiment`one.

Comment: you mean I wouldn't have to create a new branch then?

Comment: that worked great! like i wanted to, as if a commit was inserted in history before branching master to 'experiment'. However, by seeing the branches graph in Source Tree, it seems like there's only one branch, and only one color (although both branches 'master' and 'experiment' are there and correctly associated with their respective commits)

Comment: @zok, you still have to create the `experiment` branch.
You are probably seeing that on the graph beacuse the last commit are the same in both.

Comment: yep, that was the case.