# What is the difference between merging master into branch and merging branch into master?

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch called `master` and another called `dev`. Usually, I do tests and improvements on `dev`; when done, I merge it into `master`, tag it, and release new version of the application.

Now, I face a decision to make in regard to merging:

1. merge `master` into `dev`
2. merge `dev` into `master`

but I am not really sure how the two are different... Any explanation would be welcome.

Comment: Merging one branch into another is not a symmetric operation; merging `master` into `dev` is different from merging `dev` into `master`. Follow this example and the difference should become clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933056/how-can-i-do-a-bugfix-on-master-and-integrate-it-into-my-less-stable-branches/25934341#25934341

Comment: With `merge master`, you advance the `dev` branch.

Comment: master branch in GIT is a generic name which means that this is a MAIN branch that is used as a TRUNK in SVN, you can mark your Dev like your master branch but not vice versa, each time you need to start new development iteration you to need create new branch using master and when you finish this iteration you also need to merge or rebase your changes into master branch, you Dev is just one of the iterations in your development cycle

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## TL;DR

The main difference lies in where the `master` and `dev` branches end up pointing.
[image]

## Full explanation

Merging one branch into another is not a symmetric operation:

- merging `dev` into `master`, and
- merging `master` into `dev`,

are, in general, not equivalent. Here is an illustrative example that explains the difference between the two. Let's assume your repo looks as follows:

[image]

### If you merge `dev` into `master`

If `master` is checked out (`git checkout master`),

[image]

and you then merge `dev` (`git merge dev`), you will end up in the following situation:

[image]

The `master` branch now points to the new merge commit (`F`), whereas `dev` still points to the same commit (`E`) as it did before the merge.

### If you merge `master` into `dev`

If, on the other hand, `dev` is checked out (`git checkout dev`),

[image]

and you then merge `master` (`git merge master`), you will end up in the following situation:

[image]

The `dev` branch now points to the new merge commit (`F'`, whereas `master` still points to the same commit as it did before the merge (`D`).

### Putting it all together

[image]

Comment: So by "not symmetric" you just mean that the branch pointers point to different commits after the merge? Because imho the commits F and F' should be the same (content-wise, not necessarily SHA-1-wise).

Comment: @musiKk Yes that's what I mean. I use different names for `F` and `F'` because `F'` is `F`'s evil twin from a parallel universe, and would have a different SHA1 from `F`'s.

Comment: Alright! Btw what do you use do draw the slick images? They look suspiciously like the images from Pro Git...

Comment: @musiKk Nah! I wrote a [little LaTeX package](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags) for that, and I drew inspiration from the style of the diagrams in the Pro Git book.

Comment: @Jubobs - I realize you hedge your addendum slightly, but you might  want to explicitly point out the parents are reversed in the two scenarios.

Comment: @AndrewC Do you mean the way that parents of the merge commits are numbered?

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, you're right. We're getting into the weeds, though. I think I should just delete my *addendum*...

Comment: Personally I think it would be worth noting - it's a constant source of confusion in my organization.  It changes how the merge bubbles look in gitk for instance.  So when you try to follow the branch history instead of following left-most in gitk as you go down you have to keep taking the right hand path which is unexpected.

Comment: @AndrewC I agree that it's interesting, but I'm not sure this is the right place to discuss it. My addendum already goes beyond what the OP asked for. In another post, perhaps.

Comment: I'd like to add that picking a proper "first parent" (the branch which receives the merge) is a question of policy in some projects: some branch might be "blessed" to only receive merges (say, of feature branches) and not be merged to other branches.  Git does even support the `--first-parent` command-line option in its `git log` command (and its friends); reading up on it in the `git log` manual page could shed quite some light on your question, @sop.

Comment: @kostix True. I touch on that in this other answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933056/how-can-i-do-a-bugfix-on-master-and-integrate-it-into-my-less-stable-branches/25934341#25934341, but perhaps I should also mention it here...

Comment: It should have a TL;DR, I thought the it would be more different.

Comment: @Jubobs I know the question is too old. But I have a problem that relates to this question. According to your answer, two approached's pointers are different, but is there any difference between their's source code? I think they are the same, is it right?

Comment: @KenBlock I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think that the accepted answer is sufficient for the layman (and if you've been searching for this answer, you are a Git layman!!).

@jub0bs correctly describes the technical difference between the two.  But there's no direction in his answer as to which you "should" use, or why.

There will always be exceptions of course, but in the general case you'll (ahem) *always* want to merge DEV into MASTER (scenario *b* in jub0bs answer).

**Why?**

To understand *why*, you need to dig a little deeper than the high-level timeline graph that jub0bs has the conversation at.  Because at the end of both commits, when you look in your OS directory, you won't be able to tell the difference.  The naive developer will therefore tell you that it doesn't matter which way round you merge the commits.

To see the difference, you need to look at the diff-tools (which should hopefully be built into your git-client (be that SmartGit, GitKraken, or whatever).

Let's imagine this file on MASTER branch:

```
filename: my_code.txt
some (code) { includes := feature1 + feature2 + feature3; }
```

And on DEV branch we have a bug-fix that was included :

```
filename: my_code.txt
some (code) { includes := feature1 + feature2 + bug-fix; }
```

After the merge-commit (regardless of which way around you do it), you'll have:

```
filename: my_code.txt
some (code) { includes := feature1 + feature2 + bug-fix + feature3; }
```

You'll only see the difference in your Git-client.

If you merge MASTER into DEV (as per scenario *c*) your Git-client will tell you that `bug-fix` was always there as part of the main history of the file, and that at some point someone came along to wedge-in `feature3` (almost as an after-thought).  But any half-decent coder would tell you that logically, this is an incorrect interpretation of history!

What you really want to do is merge DEV into MASTER.  In this scenario, the history will tell you that `feature1`, `feature2` and `feature3` were always in-scope and planned as the main development trunk of the overall project.  `bug-fix` on the other hand, was only added as a necessary correction (after-thought or distraction) along the way.

** **EDIT** **

I'd like to add an extra comment on this to show how a "healthy" history should look.  When trying to explain VC to new developers, I've recently learned that they find it harder to grasp the concepts if I talk about MASTER and DEV branches.  Instead, its more intuitive to think of a "production" environment, and that there are bug-fixes that you need to apply to that environment.  Everyone intuitively understands that you should never put your bug-fix directly into LIVE without first passing those changes through a DEV and/or TEST environment first.  When put in these terms it should be equally obvious that you should never merge MASTER into DEV.

In a pictorial sense, your history should look something like this with all your "significant" commits on the outside lane:

[image]

An "unhealthy" history looks like this, where (essentially) Git's history is telling us that all our changes were applied directly to the LIVE system:

[image]

In conclusion: instead of thinking of the situation in technical terms (i.e. merging DEV into MASTER, or more generally BRANCH1 into BRANCH2), think of the problem in human terms: pushing your bug-fixes into Live, or maybe pushing "my new development work" into "a test environment" for the functional guys to have play with.

Maybe that helps, or maybe it doesn't.  Take it or leave it!

**Endnote:** It is a messed-up feature of Git that in order to merge "dev-to-master" you have to check out Master (and merge)!  I find this counter-intuitive because if I've just been developing on my branch I don't want to have to switch to a different branch to merge my work into it.  I always thought it would be sensible for Git to prompt which way the merge should work, but maybe that's just me!