# Difference between merge from Master and merge from branch in git

Tags: git

suppose I have a branch b1, done my development, pushed to the remote, and I want to merge into the remote master.I just wandering what's the difference between

```
git fetch
git checkout b1
git merge/rebase master
git push master
```

and

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git merge/rebase b1
git push master
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between merging master into branch and merging branch into master?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384166/what-is-the-difference-between-merging-master-into-branch-and-merging-branch-int)

Comment: indeed, I am sorry. but there is a small difference :) I'v thrown the rebase into the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the merges, your repo looks something like

```
...-- * -- * -- * -- * master

...-- * -- * -- * -- * b1
```

After `git merge/rebase master`, only `master` consists of the merged history:

```
-- * -- * -- * -- * -- * master
                      /
...-- * -- * -- * -- * b1
```

After `git merge/rebase b1`, only `b1` consists of the merged history:

```
...-- * -- * -- * -- * master
                      \
-- * -- * -- * -- * -- * b1
```

You *probably* want the first scenario, where you normally branch off `master` and would want the full history including all previous merges. However, if `b1` is a long-lived branch, you may occasionally do the second merge as well, so that `b1` keeps up-to-date with `master`.

Answer (score 1):

In first case the `b1` will have all changes from `master`, but `b1` could have something which is not in `master`.

The second case - opposite.

Just try to see different combinations in the log before/after merges: `git log b1..master`, `git log master..b1`.

Comment: what is the recommend way? and when you mean could have something which is not in master, what exactly is it? could it be something committed right after the merge command issued? the change is too small, push when you push, git won't allow you to do it isn't

Comment: @user5324782 `master` is just yet another branch, same as `b1`. There is no difference at all, except of its name. "Something" - I meant commits made into a given branch before merge. You could also make commits after, they will be just more commits after merge...