# Make a quick fix via a new Git branch?

Tags: git, github

I made some experimental change to my master branch, then I'd like to make some quick fix which is independent with the change in my master branch. I tried create a new branch, but it seems it is based on my master and I have to undo the experimental changes at first. How to I create a branch which is based on the master branch I forked from?

Comment: `git checkout -b new_branch_name origin/master`

Comment: Checkout the commit you want to branch from, then create a branch.

Comment: The main problem is that you're doing experiments in the master branch. Experiments should be done in a topic branch. I would create an experiment branch from master, then reset master to the latest non-experimental commit (i.e. probably to origin/master), then create a fix branch from master.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933056/how-can-i-do-a-bugfix-on-master-and-integrate-it-into-my-less-stable-branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new branch is only created from the current branch by default. You can specify *any* commit to base the branch on with. For example, if your history looks like

```
* -- A -- B -- C (master)
```

and `B` and `C` are your experimental commits, then run

```
git branch bugfix A
```

to create a new branch that starts at commit A instead of commit C.